# Theme hook not found

Tags: hooks, webforms

I have a custom module that implements a webform handler. I'm seeing this error in my Watchdog log when I navigate to admin/structure/webform/manage/myform/handlers:

> Theme hook webform_handler_myform_form_handler_summary not found.

I must have missed something when creating my module, but what? What needs to be added? Searches for "webform handler theme hook" haven't been fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [webform_example_handler](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/tree/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_handler)

You need to add:

mymodule/**mymodule.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Provides a custom webform handler.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'webform_handler_myform_form_handler_summary' => [
      'variables' => ['settings' => NULL, 'handler' => []],
    ],
  ];
}
```

mymodule/templates/**webform-handler-myform-form-handler-summary.html.twig**

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a summary of an example webform handler.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - settings: The current configuration for this email handler:
 *   - message: The message.
 *   - debug: Debugging flag.
 * - handler: The handler information, including:
 *   - id: The handler plugin id.
 *   - handler_id: The handler id.
 *   - label: The handler label.
 *   - description: The handler description.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{% if settings.debug %}<b class="color-error">{{ 'Debugging is enabled'|t }}</b><br />{% endif %}
<b>Message:</b> {{ settings.message }}
```

Clear/flush the cache so your new hook & template file gets picked up.